# Once item is selected from datalist, ng-change is showing result again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am a newbie to AngularJS. I have an input text box in my html code which is used to select a city, which is coming from the data base. For that I am calling the API. The results are populating the datalist, which is working fine. But as I select a item from the datalist, it is calling the method once again and it is showing the same result which I had selected. I know it is because of ng-change. can anyone give me a solution to this problem or any idea that would help me. Thanks for your help in advance

My HTML :

```
<input type="text" list="cityList" class="form-control" placeholder="Select City" ng-model="selectcity" ng-change="searcity()" class="form-control" id="seacityincoucat">
 <datalist id="cityList">
    <option ng-repeat="city in cities.results" value="{{city.name}}">
 </datalist>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.searcity = function () {
        var ciseurl = urlcs + $scope.selectcity;
        $http.get(ciseurl, config).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.status === '$200') {
                $scope.cities = response.data;
                var x = $scope.cities.results;
                couponSvc.setCityId(x[length].id);
            }else{
                alert("try some thing else");
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: That is happening because of ng-change, it will call again that method because you have change the value of texbox, try by ng-keyup

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-blur instead of ng-change

```
<input type="text" list="cityList" class="form-control" placeholder="Select City" ng-model="selectcity" ng-blur="searcity()" class="form-control" id="seacityincoucat">
```

Comment: i used the ng-blur, but as i enter any character in the input box it should call the api to get all cities list which is populating in the datalist but it is not working as it did earlier

Comment: in ng-keyup what happended that it sets the first element's id (i.e couponSvc.setCityId(x[length].id); ) from the datalist

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngKeyPress](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)

```
<input type="text" list="cityList" class="form-control" placeholder="Select City" ng-model="selectcity" ng-keypress="searcity()" class="form-control" id="seacityincoucat">
```

Comment: it sets the first elements id from the datalist. that's why i use ng-change

Comment: Can you create a Plnkr?